# In Python, how can I set a reminder on a given day?

Tags: python, date, time

I'm making a program in Python that is used to start up other programs, but I want to add a feature, say for example, that if the program is used on a wednesday, it might say 'Pick up the kids' or a similar reminder

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [built-in `time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) to get the current day of the week.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.localtime().tm_wday
5
```

The 5 indicates that it is Saturday here.

Comment: How about `datetime.date.today().weekday()`? It's slightly more readable I think.

Answer (score 0):

See [datetime.date](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) for working with dates where the time and timezone do not matter.

For readability, I would use:

```
import datetime

if datetime.date.today().strftime('%A') == 'Wednesday':
    print("Pick up the kids!")
```